# How to get input information on web app like msg box using google script

Tags: html, web, google-apps-script

I  need output on web app which key information in input box. using html and java script I deployed as web app. once key the information I should get pop up msg on web app  that information. Please help me out of this problem.

I have created HTML and javascript, using that data is getting capture in google spreadsheet but that information I should get on web app like pop up msg

Key information get in pop up msg in web app only

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<base target="_top"> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h2>US P2P Standard Notes</h2> 
<label>G-case #: </label><input type= "#" id="username"> 
<button id="btn">Pass</button> <form action="">
<p> </p> 
</form> 
<script> 
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff); 

function doStuff(){ 
var uname = document.getElementById("username").value; 
google.script.run.userClicked(uname); 
document.getElementById("username").value =""; 
} 
</script> 
</body> 
</html> 

function doGet() { 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page"); 
} 

function userClicked(name){
  var url = "docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…"; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url); 
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); 
  ws.appendRow([name + "This is G-case#"]); 
}
```

Comment: You can put code in your question and select it and enter control-k and that will indent it 4 spaces producing a clean looking code section.  Putting code in comments is not acceptable.  Please take some time to learn the tools.

Comment: I did same, but it was throwing error. Sorry for the inconvience

Comment: `alert(uname)`?

Comment: userClicked(name) this is the one typo error it should be userClicked(uname)

Comment: Thanks it;s working for me now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I have it running as a dialog.  I assume that you can take it from here and turn it into a Web App.

The html file was name aq4.html:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <base target="_top"> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <h2>US P2P Standard Notes</h2> 
    <label>G-case #: </label><input type="text" id="username" /> 
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Pass" onClick="doStuff();" /> 
  <script> 
    function doStuff(){ 
      var uname=document.getElementById("username").value; 
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(){
        document.getElementById("username").value =""; 
      })
      .userClicked(uname); 
    } 
  </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Since there was nothing in your form, I removed it.  I also changed your button style to the input version. I added a withSuccessHandler to remove the entered text.

This is the google script:

```
function userClicked(name){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var ws=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  ws.appendRow([name + "This is G-case#"]);
  return; 
}

function showDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq4');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "My Page")
}
```

Your saying something about a pop up but I haven't a clue as to what you're trying to say.  Perhaps, you can elaborate on that a bit.

Oh and this is what the current dialog looks like:

[image]